# How to filter by common value

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have fields: phone_country_code and phone_number, for example 8 (code) and 9191501490 (number)
I need find record by common value: phone, for example 89191501490
How to decide it?

Only suggesting:
err := r.Db.Where("(phone_number)+(phone_country_code)=?", phone).First(out).Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to extract country code from phone and query them separately(phone in this example does not have country code):
`r.Db.Where("phone_number=? AND phone_country_code=?", phone, country_code)`

But if you don't know by what rule they are composed you could try this:
`r.Db.Where("CONCAT(phone_number, phone_country_code)=?", phone)`